# Flutter Filemaker API _find request

Tags: flutter, dart, filemaker

Im trying to make a http-request to Filemaker with Flutter(package:http/http.dart)

I can get the token normally, but if i try the make an _find request to Filemaker it always get's rejected(**400 Bad Request**) without any message.
In Postman I can do the exact same request without issue!

```
var body = { "query":[{
  "loginName": "==testUser@test.com"
}]};
Response response = await post(url,
         headers: {
           HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
           HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'},
         body: json.encode(body));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
Dart http adds: content-type: application/json; **charset=utf-8**

And Filemaker rejects this..
But now is the question why does Filemaker API rejects such an API Call?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

I was able to access one user in a FileMaker layout using Dio.

```
  Dio dio = Dio();

   dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
   dio.options.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer ${token}";

   Response recordResponse;

   recordResponse = await dio.post(
     findUrl,
     options: Options(followRedirects: false, validateStatus: (status) 
 {return status < 500;}),
     data: { "query":
       [{
           "username": "=Jake",
           "password": "=password"
       }]
     }
   );
```