# 400 Bad Request usind Dart in Flutter app trying to connect to FileMaker Database

Tags: api, rest, flutter, dart, filemaker

[Is this still the case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453322/flutter-filemaker-api-find-request/62837191?noredirect=1#comment111120348_62837191) Can we not query FileMaker API with Flutter?

I'm gettin a 400 error.

Here is my code:

```
final recordResponse = await http.post(
  findUrl,
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader : 'Bearer ' + token
  },
  body: json.encode({"query":[{"firstname": "=Yuichi"}]}),
);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this specific problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013709/flutter-request-filemaker-api-fielddata

Comment: Yes. I solved it. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453322/flutter-filemaker-api-find-request/62837191?noredirect=1#comment111120348_62837191

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

I was able to access one user in a FileMaker layout using Dio.

```
Dio dio = Dio();

dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
dio.options.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer ${token}";

 Response recordResponse;

 recordResponse = await dio.post(
   findUrl,
   options: Options(followRedirects: false, validateStatus: (status) 
 {return status < 500;}),
    data: { "query":
      [{
          "username": "=Jake",
          "password": "=password"
      }]
    }
  );
```