# Flutter request Filemaker API (FieldData)

Tags: flutter, dart, filemaker

Im trying to access one specific call to the filemaker API, I have several requests which are working..
but if i try to do one with the fieldData field it doesn't work

```
var body = {"fieldData": {
  "testId": myId
}};

  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
  request.headers.add('authorization', 'bearer $token');
  request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(body)));
  HttpClientResponse httpClientResponse = await request.close();
  String reply = await httpClientResponse.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  httpClient.close();
```

I just get the error:

```
{"messages":[{"message":"Unknown parameter(s): fieldData","code":"960"}],"response":{}}
```

Edit:
Url: https://{Server}/fmi/data/vLatest/databases/{database}/layouts/DataAPIaddresses/records/{id}

Comment: What was the url?

Comment: It does look like you're using the wrong endpoint but post the URL as @Siva said so it can be verified. For a find request the parameter is "query".

Comment: @siva Url should be right: https://{Server}/fmi/data/vLatest/databases/{database}/layouts/DataAPIaddresses/records/{id}, if im sending an empty body it works...i also tried different http requests with flutter, it also doesnt work.. all the other requests works thats strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.patchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
```

You have to patchUrl, because Filemaker wants a Patch request...